# Linux: list unique part of file name

Tags: linux, file

I have about 50K files is a directory (linux OS) and they have naming convention as **USER_ID.ORACLE_JOB_ID.SEQUENCED_NUMBER.pdf**

I need to list all unique ORACLE_JOB_ID in a text file. How can this be done?

PS: Forgot to mention that there are some other files in same directory which have different naming convention and I have to avoid them.

Thanks!

Examples:
1.6778390.done
2.o6778390.out
3.AWRX_GBL_FAR1.98567432.4.dat.xml
**4.AWRX_GBL_FAR1.34789214.4.pdf**

Comment: What characters are allowed in each of those three fields?  If, e.g., USER_ID had no digits and ORACLE_JOB_ID had only digits, that would simplify the solution.  But the solution will likely be `ls -1 | sed yada yada yada | uniq`.

Comment: Forgot to mention that there are some other files in same directory which have different naming convention and I have to avoid them. USER_ID is alphanumeric, ORACLE_JOB_ID and SEQ_NUM are numeric

Comment: @Nitin we need to see specific examples of all naming conventions in the dir if we are to help you separate wheat from chaff.

Comment: @pilcrow Added examples in question above

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ls | awk 'BEGIN{FS="."}{ print $2 }' | sort | uniq > file.txt
```

`ls` get list of all file names in current directory

`awk` split each file name by the Field Separator ".", print only the second field

`sort` sort this second field

`uniq` remove consecutive identical lines

EDIT: if you want to limit to just the files in the current dir with .pdf use:

```
find . -iname '*.pdf' | awk 'BEGIN{FS="."}{ print $3 }' | sort | uniq > file.txt
```

using `ls *.pdf` when there are many many pdfs in the current dir will overflow the arguments into `ls`, as the error shows, because its equivalent to calling `ls` with 50K different command line arguments, overflowing `ARGV`.

Comment: I think your awk script needs to be `'BEGIN {FS="."} {print $2}'`.

Comment: your right, as I wrote it before it changes the FS only after already preprocessing the first line

Comment: Hi, Thanks for response. Forgot to mention that there are some other files in same directory which have different naming convention and I have to avoid them. So this command may not give correct result. If I give command like ls *.pdf |.. then I am getting error "Argument list too long"

Comment: @Nitin One stock way to deal with that problem is to change `ls *.pdf` to `find . -maxdepth 1 \( -type f -a -name '*.pdf' \) -print | sed 's:^\./::'`.

Comment: @qwwqwwq What's this `-iname` option of which you speak?  Also the leading `./` will mean you now need `print $3` in the awk script, I think.

Comment: good catch there with find prepending `./`! `-iname` is just case insensitive match, in case some files are .PDF and not .pdf

Comment: @qwwqwwq Thanks for correct solution bang on! **find** command worked fine.

Comment: `sort | uniq` is so common that that functionality is [built in to sort](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sort.html).

Comment: @pilcrow true ... as long as you don't need any of `uniq`'s options, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

In the spirit of "there's more than one way to do it," here is a perl one-liner which is functionally equivalent to qwwqwwq's shell pipeline:

```
perl -le 'my %seen; print for sort grep !$seen{$_}++, map { (split /\./)[1] } <*>'
```

`<*>` can be replaced with any glob expression, e.g. `<*.pdf>` to operate only on files whose names end with `.pdf`.

Comment: +1  On the upside, this will efficiently *stream* the directory, rather than reading it in all at once.  (Something even `find()` does on my system.)   On the downside, it will also `stat(2)` every matching entry.  (`find()` also does that for me, too.)

Comment: @pilcrow One could probably get around that by using `opendir` and `readdir` instead, but then you have to do the globbing yourself, and the extra code overflows my personal limit for one-liners.